# Default Values on a Shared Data Set in SQL Reports 2008

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to know if it is possible to set the default values of a shared dataset with the results of another dataset.

I am currently creating datasets to allow a user group to run ad hoc sql reporting on a SharePoint intgrated deployment.

I know how to do this in an actual report but I would like to do it in the shared dataset so that users would not then have to configure the parameters in the report when they are creating ad hoc reports.

I can see how do create default parameters if I type in the values, however the values  may change over time so I want to autmotaically pick up any changes from the database by running a query to get the appropriate values.

Has anyone achieved anything similar before or could suggest an alternative way to achieve this?

PS quite new to SQL reports. Thanks in advance